# Fantasy short story - fake church of the sun

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Think the story is relatively recent (c.2007) and I probably read it in an annual collation anthology.

It is about a group of friends who decide to set up a fake church to con people out of money. Think of something like "church of the eternal sun," with the narrator being high priest. It all ends up taking off, schisms etc, and ends up coming true with their God appearing.

It was as much comedy as fantasy from memory.

Comment: This rings a very faint bell for me, but I can't come up with the name off the top of my head.

Comment: Could be the same question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255326/story-novella-where-philosophy-students-invent-a-religion

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi:  Ha!  I hadn't even seen that other bounty was already active — I was just going through my old bookmarks and figured I'd throw some rep at this question to see if it shook anything loose.

Comment: By sheer dumb luck I think I found it based on the clues in the other question:  "The Sun & I" by K. J. Parker.  Published in Subterranean Press Magazine in Summer 2013, and available [here](https://subterraneanpress.com/magazine/summer_2013/the_sun_and_i_by_k_j_parker).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Do you want to post that answer? :) I know you can't get your own bounty, but it at least will permanently indicate the answer .

Comment: @FuzzyBoots:  Not sure;  what's the best thing to do given site policies?  I feel weird "double-dipping" like that, since I'd presumably still get some rep on both questions.  But it's a weird situation to begin with.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable, especially since we don't know if it's the same story. By providing the same answer in both places, you are providing an answer to both questions. Ideally, you'd tune each answer to the details of the question, but I feel like your answer on the other question addresses most of this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Story/Novella where philosophy students invent a religion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255326/story-novella-where-philosophy-students-invent-a-religion)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After placing a bounty on this question, I was directed to  [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255326/story-novella-where-philosophy-students-invent-a-religion?noredirect=1&lq=1) that was awfully similar.  Based on a clue from the comments on that question, and a healthy dose of sheer dumb luck, I suspect this is ["The Sun and I"](https://subterraneanpress.com/magazine/summer_2013/the_sun_and_i_by_k_j_parker) by K. J. Parker.  It was published in the Summer 2013 edition of *Subterranean Press Magazine.*

> “We could always invent God,” I suggested.
>
> We’d pooled our money. It lay on the table in front of us; forty of those sad, ridiculous little copper coins we used back then, the wartime emergency issue—horrible things, punched out of flattened copper pipe and stamped with tiny stick-men purporting to be the Emperor and various legendary heroes; the worse the quality of the die-sinking became, the more grandiose the subject matter. Forty trachy in those days bought you a quart of pickle-grade domestic red. It meant we had no money for food, but at that precise moment we weren’t hungry. “What do you mean?” Teuta asked.
>
> “I mean,” I said, “we could pretend that God came to us in a dream, urging us to go forth and preach His holy word. Fine,” I added, “it’s still basically just begging, but it’s begging with a hook. You give money to a holy man, he intercedes for your soul, you get something back. Also,” I added, as Accila pursed his lips in that really annoying way, “it helps overcome the credibility issues we always face when we beg. You know, the College accents, the perfect teeth.”

The students do have several "miracles" attributed to them (some through dumb luck, some through careful planning and foreknowledge).  However, the scheme begins to unravel when the "made-up" god appears to the protagonist in a dream and asserts His reality:

> “You made me up,” he [God] said firmly. “Let’s just think about that. You were trying to find a way to feed yourself and your friends when you were poor and hungry, and an idea came into your head.” He smiled. “Where do you think that idea came from?”
>
> “I made you up.” I couldn’t seem to get him to understand. “I invented you as part of a criminal conspiracy.”
>
> He shrugged again. “You gave me life,” he said.

The protagonist eventually breaks off from the "Orthodox" church and inspires his own schismatic sect.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had given up and forgotten about this but yes, that’s it. And randomly really got into the same authors 16 ways to defend a walled city series so obviously subconsciously took something from it!